# Extract list of objects from object list in kotlin?

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I have a list of `actions` object. I am trying to make it a list of `string` on basis of `action type`

Sample data

```
{
"wicked": "not at all",
"footer": {
"actions": [
  {
    "icon": "",
    "type": "click"
  },
  {
    "icon": "",
    "type": "click"
  },
  {
    "icon": "",
    "type": "click"
  }
]
}
}
```

These are my data classes

```
data class Footer(
val actions: List<Actions>?)

data class Actions(
val copy: String?,
val action: String?)
```

This is the code I am trying to extract string list of action types using map operator

```
dataFooter?.actions?.map { it.type }?.toCollection()
```

I am not sure what should go in the `toCollection` method.

Comment: `toCollection()` is accepting another list where you want to add mapped elements with `map`.

Comment: Why do you need to run `toCollection()` or `toList()` in the first place? `dataFooter?.actions?.map { it.type }` already returns a list of strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `toList()`

```
dataFooter?.actions?.map { it.action }?.toList()
```

If you need a list of `string` on the unique value of the type then use `toSet()`